# Firebase app crash. because image not found

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crash

I have a firebase based app that works fine when build in xcode and installed in device but when i upload it to app store for beta testing purpose it crashes on launch.

The error log is :

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher
>
> Reason: image not found

I have not designed any framework for the app.

I have been to all the other solutions and discussions in forum but nothing is resolving the matter.

has anyone else ever faced this?

Comment: Try uncommenting *use_frameworks!* in  your PodFile.

Comment: @Jay  It is already uncommented.....What can be the issue?

Comment: Have you included the Facebook API library?